# How to split a string into several strings of equal sizes

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

I have to convert a binary number to a hex number. The way I have decided to do this is to split the binary string into several strings of length 4 and assign each string its corresponding value in hex number (i.e. 1000 = 8, 1101 = D).

I have seen several question asking for a way to split a string into strings of size 4 the same thing but all of those solutions used a regex that gave a single string. For example I found this line of code in a solution:

System.out.println(Arrays.toString("String".split("(?<=\G.{4})")));

When I tried to use it with the binary number "10011000", I got "[1001, 1000]" but as a single string (the brackets, comma, and blank space were included as characters) and I was left with the same problem, how do I split a string.

Is there a way to split a string into an array of smaller strings?

Comment: The reason you got a string was because of the call to `Arrays.toString`. If you leave that out you will get an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can try making the string a char array and then into another array of strings, add each 4 characters of the char array.

Try this:

```
    String BinaryNumber = "10011010";
    
    char[] n = new char[BinaryNumber.length()];
    
    for(int i=0; i<BinaryNumber.length(); i++){
        n[i] = BinaryNumber.charAt(i);
    }
    
    String str;
    String[] NumberArray = new String[(BinaryNumber.length())/4];
    int count = 0;
    
    for(int i=0; i<BinaryNumber.length(); i+=4){
        
        str = String.valueOf(n[i])+String.valueOf(n[i+1])+String.valueOf(n[i+2])+String.valueOf(n[i+3]);
        NumberArray[count] = str;
        count++;
        
    }
```

I think this might be the solution, though it will only work if the length of the BinaryNumber is divisible by 4.

Comment: Much simpler using builtin features of Java, but with same limitation to multiple of 4: `char[] binnum = "10011010".toCharArray(); String[] strary = new String[binnum.length/4]; for(int i = 0; i < strary.length; i++ ) strary[i] = new String(binnum,i*4,4);`

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this.

```
String binaryNumber = "110101111";
// first make certain the binary string is a multiple of length four so
// pad on the left with 0 bits.

binaryNumber = "0".repeat(3 - (binaryNumber.length()+3) % 4)
        + binaryNumber;

// Then you can just split it like this as you described.
String[] groups = binaryNumber.split("(?<=\\G.{4})");

for (String v : groups) {
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

prints

```
0001
1010
1111
```